# compactness requirement for the tube lemma of a product space.

Tags: general-topology, intuition

**The tube lemma:** Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces s.t $Y$ is compact. Let $X_0 \in X$ and let $N$ be an open set in $X \times Y$ so that $x_0 \times Y$ is contained in $N$. Then there exits a neighborhood $W$ of $x_0$ such that $W \times Y \subseteq N$.

I understand the proof for this lemma, and the fact that it relies on $W=U_1 \cap...\cap U_2$ for finitely many basis elements of $x_0 \times Y$ (which is compact by homeomorphism.)

So, I can see formally how this proof relies on the finite intersection of basis elements of a compact $Y$.

However, my intuition does not follow from this. Is it the fact that the intersection of infinitely many $U_i$ need not be open? Or that the infinite intersection maybe trivial?

Munkres provides a counter-example, but I simply do not  understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X = (-1,1)$ and $Y = (1, \infty)$ and $x_0 = 0$. Consider the set

$$ N = \{ (x,y) \, | \, 0 < |x| < 1, 1 < y < \frac{1}{|x|} \} \cup (\{x_0\} \times Y). $$

Drawing $N$, we see that $N$ looks like

[image]

The set $N$ is an open set containing (part of) the $y$-axis $\{ 0 \} \times (1, \infty) = \{ x_0 \} \times Y$ and it becomes more narrow as $y$ approaches infinity. For each $0 < \varepsilon < 1$, the open rectangle $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \times (1, \frac{1}{\varepsilon})$ is contained in $N$ so given a point $(0, y_0)$ with $y_0 > 1$, we can choose $\varepsilon$ with $0 < \varepsilon < \frac{1}{y_0}$ and obtain an open product neighborhood $U_{y_0}$ around $(0,y_0)$ that is contained in $N$. However, as $y_0 \to \infty$, the base of such open product neighborhood must become smaller and smaller and the set $N$ does not contain an open set of the form $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \times Y$. The $U_{y_0} \cap Y$ form an open cover of $Y$ but they do not have a finite subcover from which one could try and extract a neighborhood of the form $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \times (1, \infty)$.

Comment: Actually, this makes sense. So I'm not entirely familiar with compactness, but does $f:X \to Y$ s.t $f$ is uniformly continuous [and $X$ is a closed bounded interval?] also satisfy the tube lemma?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean by $f$ satisfies the tube lemma?

Comment: Good point, I'm sorry. I mean that for each $X \times f(X)$, can you take $x_0 \times f(X)$, etc. And find a neighborhood $W$ about $x_0$ that satisfies the condition

Comment: perhaps that is a different question altogether, thank you for answering my question w/ an instructive example.

Comment: Well, if $X = (0,1)$ and $f(x) = x$ then $Y = f(X) = (0,1)$ but the tube lemma is false for $X \times Y$ using a similar constructing of a neighborhood around $x_0 \times (0,1)$ that becomes narrow as $y_0 \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: I see. And my question of $X$ being a closed bounded interval is also trivial, since just the continuity of $f$ (weaker than uniform continuity) implies that $f(X)$ is compact anyway. Thank you